# C# Using updated array from other method - creating a console game "Nim"

Tags: c#

I recently started trying to learn C# (no prior programming experience) and am trying to create a simple mathematical game called "nim"

I'm far from done but at the moment I'm stuck on an issue I can't seem to solve. I have two methods in the game that control whose turn it is, and how many sticks the user takes away from each pile. the "Game" method is supposed to update the array(which I think it does). but then when it goes back in to the "PlayerTurn" Method, I reset the array because I don't know how to update the value in PlayerTurn using the new updated values in "Game".

Here's the code: (sorry for it being messy)

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    class Program
    { 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Welcome();
            PlayerName();
            int[] arr = { 5, 5, 5 };
            int turn = 3;



            do
            {
                if (turn == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player one, make a move ");
                    PlayerTurn(turn);
                    turn++;
                }
                else
                {
                    PlayerTurn(turn);
                    turn++;
                }
            }
            while (arr[0] != 0 && arr[1] != 0 && arr[2] != 0);
            

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Welcome()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("welcome to nim!");
            Console.WriteLine("RULES: ");
            Console.WriteLine("The game begins with placing five sticks in three different piles.");
            Console.WriteLine("Then the players take turns picking sticks from them until they are empty.");
            Console.WriteLine("The player in turn must pick at least one stick, and they must come from the same pile.");
            Console.WriteLine("The player who has picked the last stick has won the game.");
        }

        static int Game(int[] array)
        {
            int[] arr = { 5, 5, 5 };



            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pick pile A, B or C");

                string choice = Console.ReadLine();
                if (choice == "A")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("how many sticks would you like to remove from A?");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int input);
                    arr[0] = arr[0] - input;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Pile A contains {arr[0]}, Pile B contains {arr[1]} & Pile A contains {arr[2]}");
                    return arr[0];
                }
                if (choice == "B")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"how many sticks would you like to remove from B?");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int input);
                    arr[1] = arr[1] - input;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Pile A contains {arr[0]}, Pile B contains {arr[1]} & Pile A contains {arr[2]}");
                    return arr[1];
                }
                if (choice == "C")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"how many sticks would you like to remove from C?");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int input);
                    arr[2] = arr[2] - input;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Pile A contains {arr[0]}, Pile B contains {arr[1]} & Pile A contains {arr[2]}");
                    return arr[2];
                }
                else
                {

                    return 0;
                }

            }
            while (arr[0] != 0 && arr[1] != 0 && arr[2] != 0);


        }

        static int PlayerTurn(int turn)
        {
            int[] arr = { 5, 5, 5 };

            Game(arr);
     
            if (turn % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player one, make a move");

                turn++;
                return turn;
            }
            if (turn % 2 == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player two, make a move");
                //spelare gör ett drag, ska prata med Game-metoden, eller??

                turn++;
                return turn;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error?");
                return 0;
            }
        }

  
        static void PlayerName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Type the name of player1: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + name + "!");
            Console.WriteLine("Add another player? Type Yes or No");
            string YesOrNo = Console.ReadLine();

            if (YesOrNo == ("Yes"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type the name of player2: ");
                string name2 = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + name2 + "!");
            }
            else if (YesOrNo == ("No"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You'll be playing against the computer!");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your answer must contain either Yes or No");
            }





        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Set array in class level - global scope
2. Pass array as an argument to PlayerTurn method.

Using 2nd approach:

```
static int PlayerTurn(int turn,int[] arr)
        {
            Game(arr);
     
            if (turn % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player one, make a move");

                turn++;
                return turn;
            }
            if (turn % 2 == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player two, make a move");
                //spelare gör ett drag, ska prata med Game-metoden, eller??

                turn++;
                return turn;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error?");
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

And call like:

```
                if (turn == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Player one, make a move ");
                    PlayerTurn(turn,arr);
                    turn++;
                }
                else
                {
                    PlayerTurn(turn,arr);
                    turn++;
                }
```